# How to perform complexe query that involves mapped entities in spring data/jpa?

Tags: spring, jpa

I want to perfom search query that involves two mapped entities, Chambre and TypeChambre,
i want to find chambre by TypeChambre name,

```
'''
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Chambre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TypeChambre typeChambre;
    private int numeroChambre;
    private String metrageChambre;
    private String etageChambre;
    private boolean accesHandicape;
    private boolean cohabitaion;
    private boolean etat;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class TypeChambre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private int nombreOccupant;
    private boolean etat;
    
}
'''
```

i tried this in my repository but i doesnt work

```
    List<Chambre> findByTypeChambreTypeChambreNom(@Param("chambreNom") String chambreNom);'
```

Answer (score 0):

In JPA query you have to provide nested object name and that object's field name.
In this case it would be typeChambre -> non.
Try this one:

```
List<Chambre> findByTypeChambreNom(String nom);
```